# Error : Mongoose Schema is required in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am learning from a udemy course where we build a Yelp like site but for campgrounds.

I am getting a problem every time I try to update the campground.

```
Error: "campground" is required
    at module.exports.validateCampground (/Volumes/Samip/ColtHTML/Node/Mongoose/YelpCamp/middleware.js:19:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Volumes/Samip/ColtHTML/Node/Mongoose/YelpCamp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Volumes/Samip/ColtHTML/Node/Mongoose/YelpCamp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at module.exports.isLoggedIn (/Volumes/Samip/ColtHTML/Node/Mongoose/YelpCamp/middleware.js:12:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Volumes/Samip/ColtHTML/Node/Mongoose/YelpCamp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Volumes/Samip/ColtHTML/Node/Mongoose/YelpCamp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at next (/Volumes/Samip/ColtHTML/Node/Mongoose/YelpCamp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
    at Route.dispatch (/Volumes/Samip/ColtHTML/Node/Mongoose/YelpCamp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Volumes/Samip/ColtHTML/Node/Mongoose/YelpCamp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Volumes/Samip/ColtHTML/Node/Mongoose/YelpCamp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
```

I looked through the relevant methods and schemas but cannot find anything that is causing the error. Can someone please help ?

My Joi schema looks like this

```
const Joi = require('joi');
module.exports.campgroundSchema = Joi.object({
    campground: Joi.object({
        title: Joi.string().required(),
        price: Joi.number().required().min(0),
        //image: Joi.string(),
        location: Joi.string().required(),
        description: Joi.string().required()
    }).required()
});
```

The code for updating campground :

```
module.exports.updateCampground = async (req, res) => {
const { id } = req.params;
const campgrounds = await campground.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...req.body.campground });
const imgs = req.files.map((f) => ({ url: f.path, filename: f.filename }));
campgrounds.images.push(...imgs);
await campgrounds.save();
req.flash('success', 'Successfully updated Campground');
res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${campgrounds._id}`);
};
```

The validateCampground method is like this :

```
module.exports.validateCampground = (req, res, next) => {
    const { error } = campgroundSchema.validate(req.body);
    if (error) {
        const msg = error.details.map((el) => el.message).join(',');
        throw new ExpressError(msg, 400);
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
```

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

The validateCampground method should be like this:

```
const { error } = campgroundSchema.validate(req.body.campground);
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can change your post request to this: const campground = new Campground(req.body.campground);